# Ruby 1.9.2 Unicode - Unicode Escaped Characters Being Dropped

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8

I have a string in UTF-8 (according to the .encoding.name & .valid_encoding?) and there's an escaped unicode character in it (\u009A)

"Hammarskj\u009Ald"

This SHOULD print out as "Hammarskjšld", but it just drops the grapheme. EG:

```
puts "Hammarskj\u009Ald"
p "Hammarskj\u009Ald"
```

Results in the text:

```
Hammarskjld
"Hammarskj\u009Ald"
```

It also (if I save the data in the database) drops it when its save as well. I've searched for a while, but I can't quite figure out how to unescape it (which is what I THINK I need to do). A lot of the info out there is for 1.8.7, and some of the stuff for 1.9.2 isn't quite what I need.

Anyone have any idea on how to do what I want? I seem to have a valid UTF-8 string, that all I want to do is save in the database (intact), but it always drops the escaped unicode.

Comment: \u009A is not "š" in Unicode, 9A is "š" in Windows-1252. A Unicode "š" is \u0161. Someone is lying to you if they claim to be using Unicode.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9a/index.htm This says otherwise.

Comment: @Paul, the fileformat.info site has wrong images for some characters due to the way their pages have been generated. In this case, the image shows “š” but the name is shown as `<control>` and the Category as “Other, Control [Cc].” So it is a control character, not a visible character. There’s something else in the data that is probably wrong (erroneous code conversion?): the name “Hammarskjšld” does not make sense, it should apparently be “Hammarskjöld” (with U+00F6 as the third last letter).

Comment: @Paul: do `puts "\u0161"` irb and see what you get. And then try `puts "š".to_json`. You can also look up *latin small letter "s" with caron* and *single character intro introducer* and see which numbers they are.

Comment: The reason you are seeing `š` on fileformat is that it's using the HTML character reference syntax `&#154;` to refer to the character. A long-standing browser quirk parses character references in the range 0x80–0x9F as the Windows-1252 characters of the same code unit, instead of the rarely-used-and-generally-pointless C1 control characters that are the rightful owners of that range of code points. (This behaviour is finally specified in HTML5, however it only counts for the HTML serialisation and not XHTML where normal XML rules apply and you get the correct control character.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's dropped, and not just not displayed? Maybe it is just the problem of your font having a non-displaying zero-width character in that code point.

When you take it out of the database and `p`'ed or `inspect`ed, if you're seeing the escaped character, it means it's there, not dropped. It's your printing out that's the issue.

Comment: Its in the OSX terminal, it has the font. I've seen UTF-8 chars there. But it also doesn't show up in the database (escaped), the character is just dropped. I have taken it out and inspected, its actually gone.